# Change Tiny Proxy IP per request on EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, tinyproxy

I'm fairly new to Proxy servers and how they work exactly.

I recently span up an AWS EC2 instance to act as a proxy server using tiny proxy. Everything seems to work just fine however i am curious about something. Is it possible to configure tiny proxy to use a different public IP each time it makes a request ? I looked into AWS Elastic IP's but don't quite understand how those might fit in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. Public IPs are allocated to the instance during launch. You can allocate multiple IPs using Elastic IPs like you mentioned but you can't get IPs per request like you asked. What's your use case?